# Не могу разобрать регулярку

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте, есть задача прочесть файл и удалить из него все виды комментариев, что в принципе не было для меня сложной задачей, но я столкнулся с полным непониманием регулярных выражений, из-за чего пошел гуглить. Нашел как раз таки регулярку для поиска всех типов комментариев, но проблема в том, что регулярка мне не понятна и массивна:

```
"(/\\*([^*]|[\\r\\n]|(\\*+([^*/]|[\\r\\n])))*\\*+/|[ \\t]*//.*)"
```

Не могли бы вы мне обьяснить, какая часть регулярки за какой комментарий отвечает. Я думал разбить регулярку по символу |, но в итоге программа не смогла разобрать полученный паттерн.

Comment: Да, я заметил этот момент, думаю как поправить

Comment: С этой регуляркой у вас точно будут проблемы. В `([^*/]|[\\r\\n])` обе альтернативы могут найти один и тот же текст.

Answer (score 3):

```
(
  /\\*          /* начало блочного комментария
  (
    [^*]|       не звёздочки
    [\\r\\n]|   переносы строк
    (\\*+       какое-то количество звёздочек подряд
       ([^*/]|[\\r\\n]) не звёздочка/слеш или перенос... <-- странная фигня
    )
  )*
  \\*+/         слеш после звёздочек, окончание блочного комментария
  |
  [ \\t]*//.*   // строчный комментарий, после вероятных пробелов и табуляций
)
```